# iOS - iPad layout top/botton spacing doesn't seem to do what I tell it to do

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout

I am creating this screen:

[image: storyboard]

But when I run things, I get it to look like this.

[image: when the app runs]

If you notice, the space below/above some elements looks off. Would anyone know why thing happens and how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: You've given us no details.  Are you using auto-layout?  Are you modifying the positions any where in code?  Is the first screenshot a portrait layout?  Or landscape?

Comment: Ouch. At a minimum you need to fix every warning in your project. Start by clicking on `Validate Project Settings`.

Comment: @nhgrif Isn’t “auto layout” clearly checked on the first screen? Genadinik: Also, when working with workspaces try to close other Xcode windows. I found myself in strange trouble sometimes when I had multiple windows open while using an workspace.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about why the buttons look the way they do, that is because your storyboard is set to be viewed as "iOS 6.1 and Earlier", so you're seeing the interface elements as the appear under iOS 6.1 -. Then when you run the application on your iOS 7 simulator, these same elements appear as they do in iOS 7 +, which you can see is quite different.

Then as far as the alignment problems go, I suggest you read through the 80 iPad storyboard related warnings that Xcode is generating and fix your constraints.